# Could not load type Nhibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect. Possible cause: no assembly name specified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nhibernate, nhibernate-configuration

[image: error picture]

This is the error i am getting during running the application.Could not load type nhibernate.Mssql2012.I m using sqlserver 2012 ,visual studio 2015

strong text
Web config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,Nhibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=SARVESH\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SimpleBlog;Integrated Security=True"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
      <session-factory>

      <property name="dialect">Nhibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.provider">Nhibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">Nhibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string_name">MainDatabase</property>



      </session-factory>


    </hibernate-configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

Database.cs

```
namespace simpleblog
{
    public static class Database
    {
        private const string SESSION_KEY = "simpleblog.database.sessionkey";
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        public static ISession session
        {
            get { return (ISession)HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY]; }


        }
        public static void Configure()
        {
            var config = new Configuration();
            //configure the connection strings
            config.Configure();
            //add our mappings
            var mapper = new ModelMapper();
            mapper.AddMapping<UserMap>();
            config.AddMapping(mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities());
            //create session factory
            _sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();



        }

        public static void OpenSession()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY]= _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public static void CloseSession()
        {
            var session = HttpContext.Current.Items[SESSION_KEY] as ISession;
            if (session != null)
                session.Close();

            HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove(SESSION_KEY);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the doc:

#### [3.8. XML Configuration File](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-xmlconfig)

This is a snippet of the example configuration:

```
<!-- properties -->
<property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
<property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;...</property>
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
```

The difference is in casing:

```
// current and wrong
<property name="dialect">Nhibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
// NHibernate, not Nhi...
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
```